# Exception handling in java stream reduce lambda

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to handle exceptions inside the `reduce(item,aggregator)` function for a stream in java.
This is what my original code looks like:

```java
List<ReportRow> totalList = newList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getEngagementCode()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(engagement -> engagement.getValue().stream()
                        .reduce((item, aggregator) -> 
                                new ReportRow(item.getEnvironment(), item.getApplicationName(), item.getEngagementCode(), item.getTotalHits() + aggregator.getTotalHits(), item.getServiceLine(), Float.toString(Float.parseFloat(item.getTotalCost().replace(",", "")) + Float.parseFloat(aggregator.getTotalCost().replace(",", ""))), item.getPrimaryOwnerEmail(), item.getDeploymentId()))
                        .get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this is roughly what I expect it to look like (doesn't work though).

```java
List<ReportRow> totalList = newList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getEngagementCode()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(engagement -> engagement.getValue().stream()
                        .reduce((item, aggregator) -> {
                            try {
                                new ReportRow(item.getEnvironment(), item.getApplicationName(), item.getEngagementCode(), item.getTotalHits() + aggregator.getTotalHits(), item.getServiceLine(), Float.toString(Float.parseFloat(item.getTotalCost().replace(",", "")) + Float.parseFloat(aggregator.getTotalCost().replace(",", ""))), item.getPrimaryOwnerEmail(), item.getDeploymentId()))
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new ImproperDataException("No Deployment Id present in row: "+ item.toString());
                            }
                        }
                        .get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The exception happens when I am trying to call the `ReportRow()` constructor.
What would be the way to handle this exception while still making using of collect, stream and map as in the original method ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: You are creating a new ReportRow on every reduce call. What I think you want to do is update a single instance.

Comment: @user207421 The "doesn't work" snippet is just a pseudo code example to explain the step I want to catch exceptions at - since i don't know the syntax that would work with reduce

Comment: @AdriaanKoster the creation of new ReportRow is being collected into a list - which has further code functionality. Hence, creation of a new ReportRow is valid here

Comment: What do you want it to do when it encounters an exception?  Throw the `ImproperDataException` rather then construct the list, or just skip the one entry and return the list of remaining items?

Answer (score 1):

If an unchecked exception occurs it will terminate the stream processing. This is useful in case of unexpected problems that you cannot recover from. To do this, the ImproperDataException should extend RuntimeException. For readability reasons I would move the try-catch and throw logic inside a method.

For checked exceptions you should decide what needs to happen. Either continue the process (by skipping the item or using a default value) or terminate by wrapping it in an unchecked exception. You cannot propagate checked exceptions from a stream expression.

Here is a simplified and slightly contrived example. When the ArithmeticException occurs, the costPerHit calculation is skipped in the report.

```
static class Value {
    int hits;
    int cost;

    Value(int hits, int cost) {
        this.hits = hits;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}

static class Report {
    int values;
    int hits;
    int cost;
    double costPerHit;

    Report accumulate(Value value) {
        values++;
        hits += value.hits;
        cost += value.cost;
        updateCostPerHit();
        return this;
    }

    Report combine(Report report) {
        values += report.values;
        hits += report.hits;
        cost += report.cost;
        updateCostPerHit();
        return this;
    }

    private void updateCostPerHit() {
        try {
            costPerHit = cost / hits;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Report{values=%d, hits=%d, cost=%d, costPerHit=%.2f}", values, hits, cost, costPerHit);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Value> values = List.of(
        new Value(0, 3), // causes ArithmeticException
        new Value(5, 1),
        new Value(1, 2),
        new Value(3, 8)
    );

    Report output = values.stream().reduce(new Report(), Report::accumulate, Report::combine);

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at ErrorHandling$Report.updateCostPerHit(ErrorHandling.java:42)
    at ErrorHandling$Report.accumulate(ErrorHandling.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$1ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:563)
    at interview.streams.ErrorHandling.main(ErrorHandling.java:63)
Report{values=4, hits=9, cost=14, costPerHit=1.00}
```

Actually since I am using a single ReportRow as a mutable container of sorts, it's probably better to use `collect` instead of `reduce`:

```
Report output = values.stream().collect(Report::new, Report::accumulate, Report::combine);
```

I think this might also be better for your actual code

Comment: I assume the exceptions in my logic happens with null attributes for the object item, so cascading from your logic, should I write a try-catch block to handle exceptions within the constructor of ReportRow?

Comment: First of all I think you should change the code so that a single instance of ReportRow is created as the identity of the reduce operation. In your current code you are creating a new instance at each accumulation. Further you probably need to add a combiner to facilitate the complex combination of items. See my example.

Comment: I think you might be running into a NullPointerException because you do not specify an identity value. In this case I think the identity starts off as null. So when you call your ReportRow constructor with item=null that causes the issue.